# Kotlin/Native Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, kotlin-native

I created a tensorflow library and trying get tensorflow version in my kotlin script like that

```
import tensorflow.TF_Version

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    TF_Version()
}
```

idea can link TF_Version() method to library with Ctrl+click
and there(in library) i have method

```
fun TF_Version(): CPointer<ByteVar>? {
    return interpretCPointer<ByteVar>(kniBridge0())
}

@SymbolName("tensorflow_kniBridge0")
private external fun kniBridge0(): NativePtr
```

but when i try to build and start i see this error

> /tmp/konan_temp8584442034275821874/combined.o:ld-temp.o:function Konan_start: error: undefined reference to 'tensorflow_kniBridge0'
>   error: /home/fnasibov/.konan/dependencies/target-gcc-toolchain-3-linux-x86-64/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold invocation reported errors

Please help me fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:
my .def file was

```
headers =  /home/user/.konan/third--arty/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/c/c_api.h
```

And after i add Opts to def file:

```
headers = /home/fnasibov/.konan/third-party/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/c/c_api.h

compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
linkerOpts.linux = -L/home/user/.konan/third-party/tensorflow/lib -ltensorflow
```

and regenerate klib - thats worked!